Are there any issues/concerns with assigning computed values to a ref property in Vue?
I'm reviewing some Vue code where the developer has assigned a computed value to a ref property. I've never seen this done before, and although it works, it seems odd to me.
Are there any potential issues or concerns I should be aware of?
Example code:
const filterOptions = ref({
    technicians: computed(() => technicians.value.map(tech => ({
        label: tech.name,
    }))),
});


What purpose does this ref serve? Refs are useful for reassignment, while computeds aren't usually created dynamically. If it's not reassigned then it should've been reactive() instead of ref(). If it's reassigned but computed stays the same then computed() should be created once outside ref()

This will work, but probably isn't what is desired in most cases as the technicians property on the object can be overridden or deleted, meaning you will lose access to the computed property.
Declaring the computed property outside of the ref then passing it through by reference will preserve access to it if you are referring to it elsewhere, e.g.,
const technicians = computed(() => technicians.value.map(tech => ({ label: tech.name })))

const filterOptions = ref({ technicians })


The question was, Are there any potential issues or concerns [with using ref properties rather than computed ones]? Are you arguing that the ref property is actually more suitable than a computed property?

@SmellyCat:
"The question was, Are there any potential issues or concerns [with using ref properties rather than computed ones]?"
The issue/concern is losing access to the computed property.  I list the concern, and then offer an alternative approach that preserves the property while allowing it to be used inside the object in the ref.
"Are you arguing that the ref property is actually more suitable than a computed property?"
No.
